# how to show an empty kendo grid in cshtml

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I want to show an empty kendo grid without any data in a div section, but i am not able to do that. I am not able to figure out what is wrong.
I am using the below code

```
$('#sample').kendoGrid({
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "Column1",
                title: "Column1",
                width: 140
            }, {
                field: "Column2",
                title: "Column2",
                width: 190
            }, {
                field: "Column3",
                title: "Column3",
                width: 140
            }]
});
```

Comment: When is your line of javascript code being executed?

Comment: Why do you tag this with razor? It has nothing to do with mvc or razor

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting or what is happening?

Here's a fiddle with your exact code and it appears to be working.  Are you positive that you've added the reference to the Kendo library?

[Fiddle showing it working](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/kvXVf/9/)

```
<div id="sample"></div>
```

I had to add the code snippet to post the fiddle.

Comment: I am not getting any error.The grid itself is not displayed, the kendo library reference "Kendo.Mvc.UI"has been added in layout page.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?  In dev tools, can you see the kendo library reference?  Do you see it working in the fiddle?

Comment: Is it the problem of kendo library reference? because it is not working for me

Comment: Might be.  What version of Kendo are you using?  That's an older fiddle that I modified and it's on version 2012.2.710.  Can you get other Kendo objects on the page?  Open the console and put a debugger; or breakpoint right before the grid call.  Type in 'kendo' in the console window and see if you get an object or a ReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the grid by showing a message when the grid is empty.

Check the example here: [[Empty Grid Message Example]](http://jsfiddle.net/X3kB5/1/)

```
<div id="sample"></div>
```